# Segmentation Fault if I push and pop %r15

Tags: c, assembly, x86

This is strange. So in the following code when I comment the pushq %r15 (line 9) and its counterpart popq %r15 (line 23) the code works but gives a segmentation fault otherwise.

The _initialize function is a c function that does some mallocs inside. It works fine when there is no push/pop %r15.

Any idea as to what could be going on?

```
  1   .globl _main
  2 _main:
  3         pushq   %rbp
  4         movq    %rsp, %rbp
  5
  6         pushq   %r13
  7         pushq   %r14
  8         pushq   %r12
  9         pushq   %r15
 10         pushq   %rbx
 11         subq    $0, %rsp
 12
 13
 14         movq    $16384, %rdi
 15         movq    $16384, %rsi
 16         callq   _initialize
 17
 18
 19         movq    $0, %rax
 20         addq    $0, %rsp
 21
 22         popq    %rbx
 23         popq    %r15
 24         popq    %r12
 25         popq    %r14
 26         popq    %r13
 27         popq    %rbp
 28         retq
```

Comment: Stack needs to be 16 byte aligned. You should have the same problem if you comment out any other push/pop.

Comment: probably why there's a `subq    $0, %rsp` to correct stack if needed

Comment: @Jester so how to push %r15 and still have the code work?

Comment: Change the `$0` to `$8`.

Comment: @Jester so I subq $8, %rsp and addq $8, %rsp and it works. There are 6 registers being push/pop 6 x 8 = 48 isn't it 16 byte aligned?

Comment: `call` also puts 8 byte return address on stack. Also note that all the registers you save are callee-saved so the `_initialize` will also preserve them, saving them yourself is totally pointless.

Comment: .. as long as he doesn't modify them by changing the function more...

Comment: @Jester agreed! That saving is a boilerplate used by compiler I am writing to generate other functions.